# UIView animation doesn't move the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, frame

This is the code I use for the animation.

```
        NSLog(@"SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:%f, Y:%f", self.loadingView.frame.origin.x, self.loadingView.frame.origin.y);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time animations:^{
            self.loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, self.loadingView.frame.size.width, self.loadingView.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:%f, Y:%f", self.loadingView.frame.origin.x, self.loadingView.frame.origin.y);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:%f, Y:%f", self.loadingView.frame.origin.x, self.loadingView.frame.origin.y);
        }];
```

This is the output in the console I get:

Before the animation starts:

```
SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:0.000000, Y:0.000000
```

In the animation block:

```
SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:320.000000, Y:0.000000
```

In the completion block:

```
SlideLoadingViewOut : frame: X:0.000000, Y:0.000000
```

The view doesn't move. Anyone knows why this might happen.

Answer (score 0):

Wild speculation

for some reason the animation block doesn't like CGRectMake being within the block, try creating it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone answered this earlier but for some reason his comment disappeared.
Apperntley I was changing the frame on a different thread than the main, I executed it on the main thread using, and it worked.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do work here
});
```